Python port scanning with asyncio too many open files
I am trying to build a port scanner in python using asyncio for asynchronous handling.
When trying in the PyCharm env, i don't get any error and ports and shown open as it should.
When trying in terminal, no open ports are shown and profiler tells me scanning was performed in 1.64 seconds which is weird. I don't get any error but it seems that when changing ulimit it works fine.
How could i make this too many files problem go away when trying to fast scan open ports (on the whole range up to 65535) in python ? Tried with concurrent.futures with socket but same problem.
Here is my code :
import socket
import asyncio

async def scan_port(semaphore, host, port):
    async with semaphore:
        conn = asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
        try:
            reader, writer = await asyncio.wait_for(conn, timeout=1)
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            return port
        except Exception as e:
            return None

async def scan_ports(host, port_range, limit):
    open_ports = []
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)
    scan_tasks = [scan_port(semaphore, host, port) for port in range(*port_range)]
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(scan_tasks):
        result = await future
        if result:
            open_ports.append(result)
    return open_ports

def guess_service(host, port):
    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.settimeout(1)
            s.connect_ex((host, port))
            response_bv = ""
            try:
                response_bv = s.recv(1024).decode()
            except socket.timeout:
                print(f"Response timeout on port {port}.")
            print("Initial response:", response_bv)
            if port == 21:
                s.send(b"NOOP\r\n")
            else:
                s.send(b"TEST\r\n")
            response = s.recv(1024).decode()
            service_name = socket.getservbyport(port)
            return service_name, response_bv
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error {port}: {e}")

async def main(host):
    host = host
    port_range = (0, 65535)

    try:
        open_ports = await scan_ports(host, port_range, 5000)
        print(f"Open ports : {open_ports}")
        dict = {}
        for port in open_ports:
            try:
                service_name, response = guess_service(host, port)
                dict[port] = [service_name]
                dict[port].append(response)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Guessing service on port {port} was not possible, maybe informations on this port have been hidden.")
        return dict
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Where do you close conn = asyncio.open_connection(host, port) ?

@SIGHUP well writer.close() should close the connection, also await writer.wait_closed() ensures all connections in the coroutines are closed.
